# Gmail Email Markup not working with Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-ses, google-schemas

I'm trying to send a e-mail with event markup to my guests but I'm having no success. I'm using Amazon SES to send e-mail but neither Gmail nor Inbox is showing the invite. I believe I setup the Amazon SES with the right DKIM-Signature and link my personal gmail with SES.

The full e-mail received is below

```
Delivered-To: xxxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.136.164 with SMTP id s36csp123199ioi;
    Wed, 27 Jan 2016 14:05:16 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.55.75.85 with SMTP id y82mr38139956qka.29.1453932315743;
    Wed, 27 Jan 2016 14:05:15 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <00000152851e818e-5dd6f0af-7707-4e18-b278-f918cd14773c-000000@amazonses.com>
Received: from a8-88.smtp-out.amazonses.com (a8-88.smtp-out.amazonses.com. [54.240.8.88])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t4si8059067qht.13.2016.01.27.14.05.15
    for <xxxx@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
    Wed, 27 Jan 2016 14:05:15 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 00000152851e818e-5dd6f0af-7707-4e18-b278-f918cd14773c-000000@amazonses.com designates 54.240.8.88 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.8.88;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of 00000152851e818e-5dd6f0af-7707-4e18-b278-f918cd14773c-000000@amazonses.com designates 54.240.8.88 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=00000152851e818e-5dd6f0af-7707-4e18-b278-f918cd14773c-000000@amazonses.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com;
   dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
s=ug7nbtf4gccmlpwj322ax3p6ow6yfsug; d=amazonses.com; t=1453932315;
h=From:Reply-To:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
bh=Tcg1kQlJP4+u0X7GdV2QjlipSG+mgyFwieDIo8nh/7U=;
b=XAv/G3O/QLg0qrrxctppcY7yvB/oOizgL3BNLM1LSizltSmykmywLFgTNvuwMTUH
zNJJYI6mz6gk5d5jlkS3kx25owYjL/WCq4QRybPlVTJtVvuvyKcFW9MBw7RWBcEfIQL
PYhrLy214VmxHsi1uVQUtwKvjFRAst1rDAOlenq8=
From: =?UTF-8?B?RXNkcmFzIGUgTGlhIA==?= <xxxx@gmail.com>
Reply-To: xxxx@gmail.com
To: xxxx@gmail.com
Subject: Subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="----=_Part_24077334_1650467526.1453932315024"

Message-ID: <00000152851e818e-5dd6f0af-7707-4e18-b278-f918cd14773c-000000@email.amazonses.com>
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 22:05:15 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2016.01.27-54.240.8.88
Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-1.LtLhfWkGZbBzQf+J9gUX7yOKQsymo3nzRJ+0IQqaHIo=:AmazonSES

------=_Part_24077334_1650467526.1453932315024
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "1",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "reservationFor" : {
    "@type" : "Event",
    "name" : "Title",
    "startDate" : "2016-04-16T15:00",
    "location" : {
      "@type" : "Place",
      "name" : "Name",
      "address" : {
        "@type" : "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress" : "Address",
        "addressLocality" : "City",
        "addressRegion" : "Region",
        "addressCountry" : "Country",
        "postalCode" : "13030320"
      }
    }
  },
  "underName" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "Name"
  }
}

   Email-message

------=_Part_24077334_1650467526.1453932315024
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<script type=3D"application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "1",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "reservationFor" : {
    "@type" : "Event",
    "name" : "Title",
    "startDate" : "2016-04-16T15:00",
    "location" : {
      "@type" : "Place",
      "name" : "Name",
      "address" : {
        "@type" : "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress" : "Address",
        "addressLocality" : "City",
        "addressRegion" : "Region",
        "addressCountry" : "Country",
        "postalCode" : "13030320"
      }
    }
  },
  "underName" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "Name"
  }
}
</script>
<br/>Email-Message
------=_Part_24077334_1650467526.1453932315024--
```

Comment: Did you register with Google?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

Answer (score 0):

Your email encoding is

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Thus all '=' signs will become '=3D'.

In your case:

```
<script type=3D"application/ld+json">
```

which it seems does not play well with gmail email markup.

Try to use [this](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/) as a test tool and try with and without ***3D***

You will see that w/out ***3D*** it will work and with ***3D*** it will not